# pick a string from file1, search in file2 and get the other values from file2 and paste in file1

Tags: bash

File1:

```
string1,string2,string3
```

File2:

```
string2,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

Output:

```
string1,string2,value1,value2,string3
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve this?

Comment: Agree, that some effort from yourself needs to be shown in order to solve your conundrum.

Comment: What happens to `value3,value4`? Does `value2` really need to be duplicated?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sorry for the typo. No duplication for value2, I just corrected that part. Just need value1 and value2 from file2 for that string.